# python tkinter grid rows occupied

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm quite new to Python and I've started trying to learn it to complete a small project I've been given at work.

Basically, I am trying to copy a MS access database file, retrieve certain data from the database and display it in a grid format using Tkinter and then delete the copied file as this is an important file so that method avoids some risks of my amateur code causing any problems.

I've managed to connect to the database using pypyodbc and then i have generated a query for each column of data and then created a grid widget to display this data in its respective columns.

The problem I'm having is that the rows from column 0's results seem to be occupying the rows for column 1's results and so on with the further columns results so the corresponding data is not aligned.

Here is my code so far, apologies for it not being great.

```
import pypyodbc
import shutil
import os
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()

master.title("Orders")

master.wm_iconbitmap('title icon.bmp')

Label(master, text="Order ID").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
Label(master, text="Customer").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
Label(master, text="Part No").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)
Label(master, text="Ordered Quantity").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N)
Label(master, text="Shipped Quantity").grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=N)
Label(master, text="DateReqd").grid(row=0, column=5,sticky=N)

shutil.copy2('C:/Users/twaddington/Documents/Toms Raspberry Pi Project/MRP database copy/mrp4data.mdb', 'C:/Users/twaddington/Documents/Toms Raspberry Pi Project/MRP database copy/newmrp4data.mdb')

con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/twaddington/Documents/Toms Raspberry Pi Project/MRP database copy;DBQ=C:/Users/twaddington/Documents/Toms Raspberry Pi Project/MRP database copy/newmrp4data.mdb')

cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT tblCustOrders.CustORID FROM tblStockItems INNER JOIN (tblSalesOrderDetail INNER JOIN (tblCustOrders INNER JOIN tblCusAddresses ON tblCustOrders.CustID = tblCusAddresses.AddID) ON tblSalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = tblCustOrders.CustORID) ON tblStockItems.ItemID = tblSalesOrderDetail.StockID WHERE (((tblSalesOrderDetail.OrderedQty)<>[ShippedQty]) AND ((tblCustOrders.ORComplete)=False));")

for CustORID in cursor.fetchall():
    w = Label(master, text=CustORID).grid(column=0, sticky=W)




cursor.execute("SELECT tblCusAddresses.CoName FROM tblStockItems INNER JOIN (tblSalesOrderDetail INNER JOIN (tblCustOrders INNER JOIN tblCusAddresses ON tblCustOrders.CustID = tblCusAddresses.AddID) ON tblSalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = tblCustOrders.CustORID) ON tblStockItems.ItemID = tblSalesOrderDetail.StockID WHERE (((tblSalesOrderDetail.OrderedQty)<>[ShippedQty]) AND ((tblCustOrders.ORComplete)=False));")

for CoName in cursor.fetchall():
    w = Label(master, text=CoName).grid(column=1, sticky=W)




cursor.execute("SELECT tblStockItems.MasterPNo FROM tblStockItems INNER JOIN (tblSalesOrderDetail INNER JOIN (tblCustOrders INNER JOIN tblCusAddresses ON tblCustOrders.CustID = tblCusAddresses.AddID) ON tblSalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = tblCustOrders.CustORID) ON tblStockItems.ItemID = tblSalesOrderDetail.StockID WHERE (((tblSalesOrderDetail.OrderedQty)<>[ShippedQty]) AND ((tblCustOrders.ORComplete)=False));")

for MasterPNo in cursor.fetchall():
    w = Label(master, text=MasterPNo).grid(column=2, sticky=W)



cursor.execute("SELECT tblSalesOrderDetail.OrderedQty FROM tblStockItems INNER JOIN (tblSalesOrderDetail INNER JOIN (tblCustOrders INNER JOIN tblCusAddresses ON tblCustOrders.CustID = tblCusAddresses.AddID) ON tblSalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = tblCustOrders.CustORID) ON tblStockItems.ItemID = tblSalesOrderDetail.StockID WHERE (((tblSalesOrderDetail.OrderedQty)<>[ShippedQty]) AND ((tblCustOrders.ORComplete)=False));")

for OrderedQty in cursor.fetchall():
    w = Label(master, text=OrderedQty).grid(column=3, sticky=W)



cursor.execute("SELECT tblSalesOrderDetail.ShippedQty FROM tblStockItems INNER JOIN (tblSalesOrderDetail INNER JOIN (tblCustOrders INNER JOIN tblCusAddresses ON tblCustOrders.CustID = tblCusAddresses.AddID) ON tblSalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = tblCustOrders.CustORID) ON tblStockItems.ItemID = tblSalesOrderDetail.StockID WHERE (((tblSalesOrderDetail.OrderedQty)<>[ShippedQty]) AND ((tblCustOrders.ORComplete)=False));")

for ShippedQty in cursor.fetchall():
    w = Label(master, text=ShippedQty).grid(column=4, sticky=W)



cursor.execute("SELECT tblSalesOrderDetail.DateReqd FROM tblStockItems INNER JOIN (tblSalesOrderDetail INNER JOIN (tblCustOrders INNER JOIN tblCusAddresses ON tblCustOrders.CustID = tblCusAddresses.AddID) ON tblSalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = tblCustOrders.CustORID) ON tblStockItems.ItemID = tblSalesOrderDetail.StockID WHERE (((tblSalesOrderDetail.OrderedQty)<>[ShippedQty]) AND ((tblCustOrders.ORComplete)=False));")

for DateReqd in cursor.fetchall():
    w = Label(master, text=DateReqd).grid(column=5, sticky=W)

cursor.close()
con.close()

os.remove('C:/Users/twaddington/Documents/Toms Raspberry Pi Project/MRP database copy/newmrp4data.mdb')


master.mainloop()
```

[And here is a screenshot of the issue I am facing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV0Aa.jpg)

This problem has been bugging me for a week now and i cannot seem to find a solution.

I am using Python 3.6

Any help big or small would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this make a difference?

```
for x, CustORID in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    w = Label(master, text=CustORID).grid(column=0, row=x+1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Thank you that has solved the problem! I did a lot of research and never came across the enumerate function.

Comment: No problem Tom.